# Using backing fields inside a class

Tags: c#, oop

In cases where we are using properties with backing fields, is it good practice - in terms of OOP and encapsulation - to access these backing fields directly or should we always go through the class property?

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private string _name;

   public string Name
   {
      get { return _name; }
      set { _name = value == null ? "" : value; }
   }

   public void SetField()
   {
      ...
        _name = "alice";
      ...
    }

   public void SetProperty()
   {
      ...
      Name = "bob";
      ...
   }
}
```

My instinct is to always use the property and never use the field except in the getter/setter but I don't know if this is an personal preference or there is a preferred standard or rule.

Just to clarify because I don't want to be misunderstood, I know that setting `_name` and `Name` are different things and I'm not asking if a setter like the one in my example is a good idea.

EDIT:
Im not asking if and when I should use auto properties like the duplicated question/answer mentions.

Comment: *(because we cant rely on auto properties)* -- Why not?

Comment: @DanielMann Because you can´t create any body in their getter/setter in order to implement some business-logic there? E.g. some validation before setting the actual value?

Comment: @DanielMann lets say you have some extra logic in the getter/setter

Comment: @HimBromBeere You didnt even read my question and you marked it duplicate, nowhere am I asking if I should use auto-implements or not

Comment: Why would you ever 'need' a public method to set a public property?  Needing additional logic in a getter/setter just means an auto implemented prop is the wrong choice in that case.  It doesnt mean they cant be relied upon

Comment: If you think about it, it makes sense to call the Property since you can have additional logic for the setter / getter. Performance wise it's not an issue since properties are inlined at compile time.

Comment: Not a duplicate but highly related: [Fields vs Properties for private class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545297/fields-vs-properties-for-private-class-variables). The dupe for that post is also worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As properties are nothing but a get- and set-method around a backing-field, they often implement some logic that should run when you access that property - most commonly some validations.

Imagine e.g the following property representing a persons age:

```
int Age { get; set; }
```

Without any logic you can assign **any** int to that property, e.g. a negative value. Therefor you introduce some validation in the setter:

```
int Age {
    { get => return _age; }
    { set => _age = value > 0 ? value : 0 }
}
```

In your class you usually have control about the values being set. Having said this there´s no real **need** to validate the input. However I feel it´s better to do so anyway in order to have a **single point of member-access**. Furthermore it´s simple to fortget what **valid** actually means when your class becomes bigger. Thus you may quite easy write the following which will cause you headaches when executing your code, as it bypasses your validation:

```
_age = -10;
```

In fact it´s rarely that simple. You´d have to scan all possible places where your backing-field is touched in order to determine where that invalid value came from.

So I prefer using the properties in the declaring class also.